# How can I use the --stdin option with git-for-each-ref?

Tags: git, shell, command-line, stdin

Recently, since **git 2.41.0**, [a `--stdin` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---stdin) has been added for the `for-each-ref` command. I tried using it to filter only certain refs but I failed and got this error message instead:

`fatal: unknown arguments supplied with --stdin`

What I wanted to do was to get all the branches that match a pattern given by a different command. For argument’s sake let's say that I want to get all local refs that are in `alpha` or `beta`. I was writing:

`echo 'refs/heads/alpha/**\nrefs/heads/beta/**' | git for-each-ref 'refs/heads/**' --stdin`

but it failed. I also tried writing it like:

`git for-each-ref 'refs/heads/**' --stdin <<< 'refs/heads/alpha/**\nrefs/heads/beta/**'`

but got the same error.

As of today (29/06/2023) there aren't any examples [in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_examples) showing how to use `--stdin`

Comment: It looks like you can use *either* `--stdin` **or** provide a list of patterns on the command line, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [synopsis for git-for-each-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_synopsis) says

> ```
> git for-each-ref … [ --stdin | <pattern>…​ ]
> ```

which means you need to provide **either** `--stdin` or a pattern. You are currently providing both. Remove the `refs/heads/**` argument and only use `--stdin`.

Comment: That was it, not sure how I missed the pipe `|`. Thanks!